# Python Based Code To Compare Similarity Between Sentences

Tags: python, gensim

I need to compare two strings, e.g. *Highly Toughened Steel - Unbreakable* and *Highly rugged Steel*. If they are the names of two products which are the same, I need to find out how similar the strings are. I also need to check for synonyms in the sentence.

I have already tried using Diff Sequence Matcher and the output is pretty good.

```
seq=difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a,b)
d=seq.ratio()*100
```

I was trying to look at Genism. Is it a library worth consider for such a small task? 
If so, can anyone provide a reproducible example for using Genism to compare strings?